# How to get sum of the data array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I am trying to get the sum of the data array.

```
array(499) { [0]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "19" } [1]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [2]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "15" } [3]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "19" } [4]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [5]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [6]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [7]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "19" } [8]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "19" } [9]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [10]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "21" } [11]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "21" } [12]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "21" } [13]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "22" } [14]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [15]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "19" } [16]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [17]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [18]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [19]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "19" } [20]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [21]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "19" } [22]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [23]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "21" } [24]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [25]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [26]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [27]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" } [28]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "20" }....................[498]=> array(1) { ["ping_val"]=> string(2) "19" }}
```

Below is how I am trying to get the sum of `ping_val`

```
 foreach ($arr as $k=>$subArray) {
        foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
            $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
        }
    }
```

When I run my code I am getting below error.

> Undefined index: ping_val at line $sumArray[$id]+=$value;

How to get rid of this error?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: number array_sum ( $array ) will it work?

Comment: @ShadabSiddiqui not it's not working either

Comment: Oddly enough you get an error that 'ping_val' does not exist, yet your code does not have any mention of 'ping_val'. Nevermind I see what you did now. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: this is not an error, it's a warning, are you printing out the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that message because the key does not yet exists in the array that you want to write to. You could first check if the key in the array exists:

```
$sumArray = [];
foreach ($arr as $k=>$subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
        if (!array_key_exists('ping_val', $sumArray)) {
            $sumArray['ping_val'] = $value;
            continue;
        }

        $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
    }
}
var_dump($sumArray);
```

That will give you:

```
array(1) {
      ["ping_val"]=>
      int(39)
    }
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/fbmiW)

You could also use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) with [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
$arr = [
    [
        "ping_val" => "19"
    ],
    [
        "ping_val" => "20"
    ]
];

$sum = array_sum(array_column($arr, 'ping_val'));
echo $sum; // 39
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/qhvtu)

Comment: By applying your 2nd method I am able to get a `sum`. after that I am trying to get `foreach($arr as $i)
        {
            // sum of squares of differences between
            // all numbers and means.
            $variance +=round(pow(($i - $average), 2),3);
        }` but I am getting `Unsupported operand types`

Comment: Try `$pow = pow(($i['ping_val'] - $average), 2);` because `$i` refers to the array in the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

> This is explanation of what is the problem.
>   The "correct solution" is posted by "The fourth bird".
>   Allthough this code works too I think you should go with The fourth bird's answer.

You have not created the array item 'ping_val' in the sumarray.
That is why you get the notice.
Your code says add something to something that does not exist, and that something that does not exist is the problem.

One solution is to create the array item prior to looping:

```
$sumArray['ping_val'] = 0; // this creates a 0 ping value and anything added will not create an notice.
foreach ($arr as $k=>$subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
        $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
    }
}
```

---

A simpler version of the same code is:

```
$sumArray['ping_val'] = 0; // this creates a 0 ping value and anything added will not create an notice.
foreach ($arr as $k=>$subArray) {
    $sumArray['ping_val']+=$subArray['ping_val'];
}
```

This only loops the first level of the array.
And in this case that is all we need since we know we need the 'ping_val' in the subarray.

Comment: `$sumArray['ping_val'] == 0;` gives `undefined variable $sumArray..`

Comment: Sorry.. that should be only one `=`

Comment: I got the sum. Now, if I want it to use against any operand it doesn't works for me

Comment: `$variance +=round(pow(($i - $average), 2),3);` at this point

Comment: That is a different question and you should know that. If that was included in the question at start I would not mind but adding to a question line this is not ok.